Can I broadcast weights from a client to the rest of the clients in federated_tensorflow?
I want to make clients talk to each other directly in tensorflow federated. I can see there's a federated_broadcast function to broadcast messages from the server to clients. Is there a different function that a client can invoke to broadcast a message to the rest of clients?
I tried looking in the official docs but haven't been able to find anything helpful.
